# How to create a *generic* zero-sized type instance in Rust?

Tags: rust

How to create an instance of the zero-sized type if that type is a **generic type parameter**?

**(!) I'm not interested** in the answer provided by "The Rustonomicon" [9.10. Handling Zero-Sized Types](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/vec/vec-zsts.html), fragment `Some(ptr::read(NonNull::<T>::dangling().as_ptr()))`.

E.g.

```rs
fn get<T>() -> Option<T>
    if size_of::<T>() == 0 {  // If the type parameter T is a zero-sized type
        return Some< ??? >    // then return the instance of that type.
    // Otherwise return something different.
```

What can I place instead of `???` in the code above?

Ideally I want this code to work for any zero-sized type passed as `T`,

- whether that type [implements `Default`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/default/index.html) or not,
- whether that type is

  - an empty struct (`struct Zst;`, `struct Zst{}`),
  - empty tuple (`()`)
  - empty or single-value enum (`enum Zst;`, `enum Zst { TheOnlyValue }`)
  - empty array(`[u8; 0]`)
  - any other zero-sized type
  - a combination of those listed above (struct/array/tuple of those, etc.)

---

Eventually I need the following:

```rust
impl<T> Iterator for RawIter<T> {   // Some generic code.
    type Item = T;
    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        if size_of::<T>() == 0 {  // If the type parameter T is a zero-sized type
            Some< ??? >           // then return the instance of that type.
```

---

**Correction**

- 2023.12.05 19:00 PST:
  **(!) I'm not interested** in the answer provided by "The Rustonomicon" [9.10. Handling Zero-Sized Types](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/vec/vec-zsts.html), *because the fragment `Some(ptr::read(NonNull::<T>::dangling().as_ptr()))` (and `*std::ptr::NonNull::<T>::dangling().as_ptr()`) seems causing undefined behavior in two ways, see [this issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/reference/issues/1433) items 3.B (dangling ptr deref) and 4 (uninit mem read)*.
  FYI: @kmdreko, @chayim-friedman.
  Also `std::mem::MaybeUninit::<T>::uninit().assume_init()` seems having a risk of causing undefined behavior (uninit mem read), see [assume_init() Safety](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/mem/union.MaybeUninit.html#safety-1) and [this issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/reference/issues/1433) item 4.
  FYI: @chayim-friedman, @ballpointben.
  Of remaining 2 @chayim-friedman 's items the `std::mem::zeroed::<T>()` seems winning since it is shorter than its synonym `std::mem::MaybeUninit::<T>::zeroed().assume_init()`.

Comment: Using `NonNull::dangling` was what I was going to propose; why is it not sufficient? Any answer would likely require `unsafe` usage since you've rejected the normal way to create an instance of a type (using `Default`).

Comment: `enum Zst;` is not valid Rust, creating a value of `enum Zst {}` is UB.

Comment: Is transmuting `()` into a ZST always sound?

Comment: @kmdreko, simulating a read from a dangling pointer (even if the read is a no-op) does not look "normal way" to me ;-), because it can at least result in a redundant `ptr::read()` code in the executable. What looks normal way is something like `T()` (a call to a default constructor in C++).

Comment: Rust uses generics entirely through traits and the trait that says something can be default constructed is `Default`. There isn't anything specially made for constructing ZSTs generically.

Comment: What you want can't be done without `unsafe`. If I write a library with a public ZST, but without a default constructor, it is probably that I have some constructor that handles some kind of state. And the `Drop` impl will release that state, whatever it means. If there were a safe way to create a ZST generically my library would break apart. And using `unsafe` you already know how to do it, you linked to the answer in the question.

Comment: Your "correction" section is baffling... Your linked self-analysis of the potential for UB seems to miss the mark. You should read the `std::ptr` section on [safety](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/ptr/index.html#safety) that says *"The canonical way to obtain a pointer that is valid for zero-sized accesses is NonNull::dangling"* which should immediately put that line of reasoning to rest. I'm also unconvinced about your understanding of `.assume_init` - yes reading uninitialized memory is UB but a zero-sized object by definition has no memory to read.

Comment: See what I answered to you in the issue. The code in the nomicon and here is valid.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are multiple possible ways to construct a ZST:

- `std::mem::zeroed::<T>()`
- `std::mem::MaybeUninit::<T>::uninit().assume_init()`
- `std::mem::MaybeUninit::<T>::zeroed().assume_init()`
- `*std::ptr::NonNull::<T>::dangling().as_ptr()`

Etc..

[There is also an accepted API Change Proposal for a `conjure_zst()` function that will become THE way to construct a ZST](https://github.com/rust-lang/libs-team/issues/292), but it is not yet implemented as of writing.

**However**, note that constructing arbitrary ZSTs (or any type) is unsound, as types can carry invariants. For example, the following code is perfectly sound:

```rust
pub struct ImpossibleToConstruct(());

impl ImpossibleToConstruct {
    pub fn cause_ub(self) {
        unsafe { std::hint::unreachable_unchecked() };
    }
}
```

But if you provide a `get()` function to construct an arbitrary ZST, the user can cause UB in safe code:

```rust
get::<ImpossibleToConstruct>().cause_ub();
```

Admittedly, this example is pretty stupid, but there are plenty of use-cases for ZSTs that carry invariants.

So if you want to provide such function, it will have to be `unsafe` (a role which the abovementioned `conjure_zst()` should fill in the future) or constrained by some `unsafe trait SafeToConjureZst` (which you can provide a `#[derive]` for, to make the user code all safe, but at this point you are better using [`bytemuck::Pod`](https://docs.rs/bytemuck/latest/bytemuck/trait.Pod.html) with `bytemuck::cast::<(), T>(())` to do it all safely).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following. Although note that it will panic when trying to instantiate an uninhabited type through `MaybeUninit::assume_init`.

```rust
use std::{mem::{size_of, MaybeUninit}, marker::PhantomData, any::type_name, fmt};

fn get<T>() -> Option<T> {
    if size_of::<T>() == 0 {
        Some(unsafe {MaybeUninit::uninit().assume_init()})
    } else {
        None
    }
}

#[derive(Debug)]
enum E0 {}
#[derive(Debug)]
enum E1 { OnlyOne }
#[derive(Debug)]
struct S { x: E1, y: E1, z: () }

fn print_it<T: fmt::Debug>() {
    println!("{} -> {:?}", type_name::<T>(), get::<T>());
}

fn main() {
    print_it::<i32>();
    print_it::<()>();
    print_it::<[String; 0]>();
    print_it::<PhantomData<i32>>();
    print_it::<S>();
    
    // this will panic at `assume_init` because E0 is uninhabited
    print_it::<E0>(); 
}
```

```
i32 -> None
() -> Some(())
[alloc::string::String; 0] -> Some([])
core::marker::PhantomData<i32> -> Some(PhantomData<i32>)
playground::S -> Some(S { x: OnlyOne, y: OnlyOne, z: () })
```

Comment: The `get()` defined here needs to be an `unsafe fn`. Constructing a value of an arbitrary type, even if it is a ZST, may violate that type's invariants about how many instances of it exist when. (It would be sound if such a value had to be consumed previously — that's how `Vec<()>` works, more or less — but not if it's totally unrestricted.)